# CGContextRef rotation not working

Tags: ios, rotation, core-graphics, cgcontextref

I wanted to rotate the contents of the CGContextRef with -90 degrees.
I found some code but it is not working correctly.

```
CGContextRef tempColorRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, bitsPerComponent,
                                                  bytesPerRow, colorspace,
                                                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGImageRef colorImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(colorContextRef);
CGContextTranslateCTM(tempLayerRef, width / 2, height / 2);
CGContextRotateCTM(tempLayerRef, DegreesToRadians(-90));
CGContextScaleCTM(tempColorRef, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextDrawImage(tempColorRef, CGRectMake(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height), colorImageRef);
CGImageRelease(colorImageRef);

colorContextRef = tempColorRef;
```

Anyone help me please.

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean? Do you experience nasal demons or what?

Comment: The contents have disappeared.

Comment: I'm sure the math part is screwed up and you're drawing *outside* the context. What if you remove the scale part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the H2CO3's comments, I tried various transformations.

It was my fault. `width` and `height` were `size_t` variables, so these can't hold minus values. The error was happening in the following instruction.

`CGRectMake(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height)`

It's working fine now.